# Implement View Controller (Tab Item) as CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, contactpicker

I have an application that consists of a tab bar, and one of the tab items is titled "Contacts". When the user selects this item, I would like to present them right away with the `CNContactPickerViewController`. Currently, I have a controller, `ContactsController`, set for the tab item for "Contacts". When the view is loaded, this code is run in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: false, completion: nil)

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

I feel like this is inefficient, as I have to load a view, only to present another view. I have tried searching around to see if there is any possibility I could convert my `ContactsController` from a `UIViewController` to a `CNContactPickerViewController`, but had no luck. The default phone application for the iPhone has exactly the feature I am looking for when you select contacts. Is there anyway to recreate this? Thanks!